# Auto update Google Map Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a Google Map showing a marker with my current position, how can I get this marker to automatically update to a new position for example every 15 seconds with Jquery?

My Code:

```
var x=document.getElementById("message");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='100%';
  mapholder.style.width='100%';

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
  }

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
```

Basicly what I'm trying to du is to update the marker and move it to the new position every 15 seconds or so, and at the same time remove the old marker.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To run some function at specified interval you can use the `setInterval()` method.

```
setInterval(function(){
    //....
}, 3000);
```

I've updated your sample http://jsfiddle.net/gNQRB/381/

See further information about the `setInterval` method here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp